# What can I do against file corruption?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

Recently, almost every file I try to copy into my HDDs gets corrupted.

- When writing to the disk, some portion of the file is replaced by random bytes (Checked using Diff apps)
- There's no problem reading existing files.
- I'm pretty sure it's not the HDD, becasue I've tried another HDD (a brand new 1TB WD) and the problem still remains.
- I have an AMD Athlon 64 X2 CPU, an ASUS M2NE motherboard, 2 WD SATA II HDDs (320GB + 1TB) and 3GB of Corsair RAM.
- My OS is Windows 7 (64 bit)

Now, what could be the cause of this?

If it's the motherboard, can it be fixed by using a PCI SATA card?

Answer (score 0):

Though it sounds like it is not a fault on the hard drive, I suggest you try those hard disks on another computer.

Can you try connecting a usb hard drive? This might determine if the problem is located in your software or firmware/hardware.

Check your cables, swap if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Vista and Windows 7 after a clean install, I had to do another clean install to solve it unfortunately. The issue seemed to be related to using the format tool in setup, the second time around, I deleted the partition, made a new partition, but this time skipped using the format tool, just let setup continue to install on the new unformatted partition. (it formats it during the expanding files routine).
All was good after that.

You could also have a bad memory stick or motherboard/driver issue.